# How to print environment value using GetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, visual-c++, environment-variables

I am learning C++. I need to print the environment value of a particular environment variable. I am finding examples to check whether a environment variable is defined or not. But how to print the environment value.

`GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("path"), Buffer, _MAX_PATH);` returns `DWORD` and it is printing some integer but I need to print the exact value something like "C:\programfiles\windows".

In C# I can do this using

```
string abc = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
cout<<a;
```

How to do this in VC++. Thanks

Comment: Please check `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130180/how-to-use-vs-c-getenvironmentvariable-as-cleanly-as-possible`

Comment: I read that but I need to print the environment value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_MAX_PATH` is not probably enough to hold the whole value. You should first call the method with a nullptr and size 0 to get the size required and then allocate a buffer of that size.

```
auto size = GetEnvironmentVariableA("PATH", nullptr, 0);
std::string Buffer(size, 0);
GetEnvironmentVariableA("PATH", &Buffer[0], size);
std::cout << Buffer << std::endl;
```

UPDATE: For pre C++11 compilers:

```
DWORD size = GetEnvironmentVariableA("PATH", NULL, 0);
```

Comment: I am getting error 
`C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`
`error C2065: 'nullptr' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: I changed it auto to int. I am using VS 2005 and not VS 2010

Comment: Should be `DWORD` actually, that's what `GetEnvironmentVariable` returns.

Comment: yes but what about nullptr how can I use it in VS 2005

Comment: Just replace it with `NULL` or `0`.